# How to customize getUser() function's return response in symfony custom provider?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony's guard authentication for the token authentication for my api. It works fine if someone provide correct authentication token but when token is empty or not correct then getUser() function throws me exception.

```
{
    "message": "Username could not be found."
}
```

I have customized this message using `CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException` like below

```
{
    "message": "Auth token required."
}
```

**But what i actually need is like this.**

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Auth token required."
}
```

Please help me for this. I have seen many tutorials on this but no luck. If you need more information then i can provide you as well. Please ignore grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Custom User Provider. Read here.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: I have read this so many times but didn't found any solution. They provide just customize error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer,

You can use `onAuthenticationFailure` method for customize error message.

I have done like this.

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $data = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Authentication Required'
    );
    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
```